# Global sections of canonical line bundles on curves in low genus

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

Let X be a curve with genus one (i.e. elliptic) or two. Let $\omega$ be the canonical line bundle. What is the dimension of the global sections of the line bundle $\omega^{\otimes n}$?

I think this is can be done using Riemann-Roch, though I'm not sure. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You're right that this can be done with Riemann-Roch - what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Assume $g \ge 2$ for now. This can be done using Riemann-Roch, which reads as follows
$$
\ell(D)-\ell(K-D) = \deg(D)+1-g.
$$
Now, set $D=nK$ for $n\ge 2$. For degree reasons, $\ell(K-D)=0$, while $\deg(D) = n(2g-2)$. Rearranging gives
$$\ell(nK) = n\deg(K)+1-g=2ng-2n+1-g=(2n-1)g-2n+1=(2n-1)(g-1).$$
If $g=1$, then $\omega_X$ is trivial and hence so is $\omega_X^{\otimes n}$, so the answer is $1$.

Comment: Thanks! Why is $\omega_X$ trivial for an elliptic curve? (haven't done any math/Langlands stuff in years, I've forgotten basics lol)

Comment: Using Riemann--Roch a number of times, one concludes that $\operatorname{deg}(K) = 0$ and $\ell(K) = 1$. This tells us $\omega_X$ has a global section $\sigma$ with no zeros. (Indeed, it has no poles and so the number of zeros is the degree of the line bundle.) We can then view $\sigma$ as a map $\mathcal{O}_X \to \omega_X$ which is an isomorphism because it vanishes nowhere.

Comment: Just a comment : the topological intuition is that a genus $1$ Riemann surface is a (complex) torus and tori have trivial tangent/cotangent bundle because of the Lie group structure. But, Brian's argument is more general.